# What format does Google Chrome Developer Tools save data as?

Tags: google-chrome, file-association

I am using Google chrome's developer tools to inspect the timeline of some requests. There is the option of storing them as a .HAR file, but I could not find anything that opens it. In a browser, it looks like a simple text file.

Does anybody know how to save Developer Tool's data in a suitable format or how to open .HAR files?

Answer (score 18):

The HTTP Archive format (HAR) format is intended to be a [format for sharing HTTP data across tools](https://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/10/19/http-archive-specification-firebug-and-httpwatch/). Although there are a [bunch of tools](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-adopters/) that support HAR & allow exporting, only a few among those appear to allow import:

- HAR Viewer ([offline](https://github.com/janodvarko/harviewer/), [online](http://www.softwareishard.com/har/viewer/))
- [PCAP Web Performance Analyzer](https://web.archive.org/web/20200506001340/http://pcapperf.appspot.com:80/)
- [Fiddler](https://web.archive.org/web/20151204090300/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/fiddler/archive/2010/06/30/import-and-export-http-archives-from-fiddler.aspx)
- [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/version-history/)
- [HTTPWatch](https://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/10/19/httpwatch-version-62-supports-data-exchange-with-firebug/)
- [HAR Analyzer in Google Apps Toolbox](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/)

Comment: Is there any way to open this directly with Chrome?

Comment: @Pacerier Yes. It's just a JSON file.

Comment: This has always baffled me - why does Chrome allow you to save HAR files but not open them?

Answer (score 7):

`.har` seems to be an [HTTP Archive Spec file](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/http-archive-specification). You can use [HTTP Watch](http://www.httpwatch.com/features.htm) to open such files. FWIW those are JSON files

Comment: Httpwatch v8.5 throws exception on Chrome 32 .har trace. "onContentLoad value in /pageTimings is not an integer value :(  Im using this one: http://ericduran.github.io/chromeHAR/

Answer (score 4):

Starting in Chrome 62 you can simply:

> Drag and drop a HAR file into the Network panel to import it.

(From the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/devtools-release-notes#har-imports).)